# semantic-ui-react Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react to build a form for a new user:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {createUser} from '../../../actions/userAction';

class UserAddModalForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleSubmit(event, props) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let body = {
        lastname: event.target.lastName.value,
        firstname: event.target.firstName.value,
        username: event.target.userName.value,
        email: event.target.email.value,
    }
    props.dispatch(createUser(body));
    props.onCancel();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmit(event, this.props)>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input name='lastName' />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input name='firstName' />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input name='userName' />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input name='email' />
          </Form.Field>
          <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
          <Button onClick={ this.props.onCancel }>Cancel</Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UserAddModalForm;
```

When I build I receive this error:

```
./src/components/ui/users/UserAddModalForm.js
Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (30:10)

  28 |             <input name='lastName' />
  29 |           </Form.Field>
> 30 |           <Form.Field>
     |           ^
  31 |             <label>First Name</label>
  32 |             <input name='firstName' />
  33 |           </Form.Field>
```

I've googled around and as far as I can tell I am enclosing my JSX element in a div. I've used semantic-ui-react components in other parts of my application with no error, I'm at a loss for why the build is hanging up on this.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to close your submit function. Add a closing curly brace

Comment: @fungusanthrax - christ I've been looking at this for 40 minutes, THANK YOU

Comment: Please note when you receive an error around an area that is seemingly OK, usually the error is located above that area as when the compiler runs the code down that's where the error will occur since something broke it above

Comment: @fungusanthrax - noted, thank you again!

Comment: @fungusanthrax consider posting your comment as an answer so the OP can accept and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmit(event, this.props)>
```

should be

```
<Form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmit(event, this.props)}>
```